# Transfer list in php in another list

Tags: php

I have a list of words for example this one

```
$words1="Les voitures Le compteur principal capteurs(gaz et l'éclairage) l'humidité L'extérieur"
```

and i want to have the list like this:

```
$words2="Les","voitures","Le","compteur","principal","capteurs(gaz","et","l'éclairage)","l'humidité","L'extérieur"
```

i did the split a string by string of the list using **explode** and then i did not find how to add the "," between the strings:

```
$text_list =explode(" ",$words1);
```

Comment: `$words2="Les","voitures","Le","compteur","principal","capteurs(gaz","et","l'éclairage)","l'humidité","L'extérieur"` isn't a valid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Online Test](https://3v4l.org/PeoMg)

First explode the string as `" "`, and then implode the using `" , "` and also add the `"` before and after implode.

```
$text_list = explode(" ",$words1);
echo $words2 = '"'.implode('","', $text_list).'"';
```

you will get:

```
"Les","voitures","Le","compteur","principal","capteurs(gaz","et","l'éclairage)","l'humidité","L'extérieur"
```

As per your requirement:

```
$words2 = explode(",", '"'.implode('","', $text_list).'"');
echo gettype($words2); //array
```

**`print_r` of `$words2`:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Les"
    [1] => "voitures"
    [2] => "Le"
    [3] => "compteur"
    [4] => "principal"
    [5] => "capteurs(gaz"
    [6] => "et"
    [7] => "l'éclairage)"
    [8] => "l'humidité"
    [9] => "L'extérieur"
)
```

Another way:

```
$words2 = array('"'.implode('","', $text_list).'"');
echo gettype($words2); //array
```

**`print_r` of `$words2`:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Les","voitures","Le","compteur","principal","capteurs(gaz","et","l'éclairage)","l'humidité","L'extérieur"
)
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean?

Comment: i tested and it works to transfer it to a string type
I need to be an array of strings with the new format.
echo gettype($words2);  must be array.

Comment: @HamdiCharef, as per your requirement, i update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make an array from the string, your approach is valid - just use the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. But if you're trying to replace the space in the string with commas, you can use the [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

```
$words1="Les voitures Le compteur principal capteurs(gaz et l'éclairage) l'humidité L'extérieur";
$commaSeparatedString = str_replace(' ', ', ', $words1);
```

Further, you can explode the result by space, to get each word with comma in a simple array.

```
$result = explode(' ', $commaSeparatedString);
```